# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with columns like this:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(list(df)) #list(df) = ["2017-01", "2016-01", ...]
```

Then I performed an interpolation in each row of the dataset because I have some NaNs that I want to get rid off. Here is the result printed:

```
ORIGINAL  
2007-12-01     NaN 
2008-12-01     NaN 
2009-12-01     NaN 
2010-12-01   -0.35 
2011-12-01    0.67 
2012-12-01     NaN 
2013-12-01     NaN 
2014-12-01    1.03 
2015-12-01    0.37 
2016-12-01     NaN 
2017-12-01     NaN 
Name: row1, dtype: float64 

INTERPOLATION  
2007-12-01   -0.350000 
2008-12-01   -0.350000 
2009-12-01   -0.350000 
2010-12-01   -0.350000 
2011-12-01    0.670000 
2012-12-01    0.790219 
2013-12-01    0.910109 
2014-12-01    1.030000 
2015-12-01    0.370000 
2016-12-01    0.370000 
2017-12-01    0.370000 
Name: row1, dtype: float64
```

Then I try to plot the interpolated row and get:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'
```

The whole code:

```
print("ORIGINAL\n", series)
interpolation = series.interpolate(method=func, limit=10, limit_direction='both')
interpolation.plot()
print("INTERPOLATION\n",interpolation)
```

It seems to me that the error is in the time values in the series, but I think matplotlib should be hable to handle it, so I'm doing something wrong for sure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 77):

Here is the simplest answer,No need to upgrade or downgrade the pandas.

```
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
```

sometime registering causing another error which is like ***compute.use_bottleneck, use_numexpr error*** for getting rid of that call deregister :P

Like: `pd.plotting.deregister_matplotlib_converters()`

source:[Link](https://darektidwell.com/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-period-facebook-prophet-and-pandas/)

Comment: Thanks. Definitely the easiest solution on pandas 0.25

Comment: Thank you - this addresses the specific issue I was facing with pandas 0.25 & fbprophet 0.5. Did not occur with pandas 0.25 & fbprophet 0.3.

Comment: Superb, how did you figure this one out.

Comment: When using your solution I'm getting: `TypeError: Axis must have 'freq' set to convert to Periods`. Running on pandas 1.1 and matplotlib 3.3.2.

Comment: @MarcelMotta once you have this error just add the following code : `df.index = df.index.to_timestamp()`

Answer (score 6):

It works if I do:

```
plt.plot(row.index, row.values)
plt.show()
```

I don't know why though...

Comment: Strange... but this solved my issue having pandas==0.25.3 and fbprohpet==0.5

Comment: type(row.index) returns: built-in method index of Pandas object at 0x000001D763176678 and I cannot plot directly.  Does the code above work?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Pandas, and will be fixed by the [next major release by August 31, 2018](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14763) if everything goes swimmingly.

For now, @J63's workaround have to do. That, or install an earlier version of pandas, such as 0.20.2.

Comment: Or you can revert to pandas 0.20.2. That resolved it for me.

Comment: Which you do with > pip install pandas==0.20.2

Comment: Faced the problem with current 0.20.3 and fixed by going down to 0.20.2 as @CarlSmith mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Copied your Interpolation results

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
df.columns = ['Period','Value']
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'])
df  = df.set_index('Period')
print(df)

               Value
Period              
2007-12-01 -0.350000
2008-12-01 -0.350000
2009-12-01 -0.350000
2010-12-01 -0.350000
2011-12-01  0.670000
2012-12-01  0.790219
2013-12-01  0.910109
2014-12-01  1.030000
2015-12-01  0.370000
2016-12-01  0.370000
2017-12-01  0.370000


df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thats odd.        ``` print("ORIGINAL\n", row) ; row.plot() ; plt.show() ``` gives the same error for me. So for the printed values the plot works, but for the stored type "Period" doesn't...