# Plot datetime.time in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

Hi I am having trouble plotting a datetime with seaborn. I am trying to plot a categorical data with x as datatype `datetime.time` but I get these error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'
```

This is my df:

```
       toronto_time             description
0      00:00:50                   STATS
1      00:01:55                   STATS
2      00:02:18                   ONLINE
3      00:05:24                   STATS
4      00:05:34                   STATS
5      00:06:33                   OFFLINE
```

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
sns.swarmplot('toronto_time', 'description', data=df);
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE:**

dtype of 'toronto_time' is an object. When I used pd.to_datetime it converts to datetime however it adds a date.

Comment: This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57148021 also works for the present question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could do in this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df['toronto_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['toronto_time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
sns.scatterplot(df['toronto_time'], df['description'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Now I am figuring how would I make the xticks as 'hours' only (0:00 - 24:00)