# Seaborn violin plot using arrays - Error: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to generate several violin plots in one, using seaborn. The dataframe 
I use includes several categorical values in one column (to be used on the x-axis), with an array of values for each categorical value (to be used to create the violin plot for each categorical value). A small working example would be this:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Names','Values'])
for i in range(10):
    foo.loc[i] = ['no'+str(i),np.random.normal(i,2,10)]
```

But when trying

```
sns.violinplot(x='Names', y='Values', data=foo)
```

I get the following error

> ValueError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric.

Now I could be hacky and just separate the array across several rows as such:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Names','Values'])
for i in range(3):
    bar = np.random.normal(i,2,10)
    for j,b in enumerate(bar):
        foo.loc[i*10+j] = ['no'+str(i),b]
```

which yields the plot I want:

[image]

But I'm guessing there is a more simple solution to this, without needing to restructure my dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) helps you turn your column of lists into separate cells. After converting them to actual numbers instead of strings `sns.violinplot` can plot without effort.

```
foo = foo.explode('Values')
foo['Values'] = foo['Values'].astype('float')
sns.violinplot(data=foo, x='Names', y='Values')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In pandas 0.25 you could use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), for a previous version use any of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
result = foo.explode('Values').reset_index(drop=True)
result = result.assign(Names=result['Names'].astype('category'), 
                       Values=result['Values'].astype(np.float32))

sns_plot = sns.violinplot(x='Names', y='Values', data=result)
```

**Output**
[image: violin plot of categorical data]

Exploding (or unnesting) will transform your data into:

```
   Names     Values
0    no0   3.352148
1    no0   2.195788
2    no0   1.234673
3    no0   0.084360
4    no0   1.778226
..   ...        ...
95   no9  12.385434
96   no9   9.849669
97   no9  11.360196
98   no9   8.535900
99   no9   9.369197

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

The [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) transforms the dtypes into:

```
Names     category
Values     float32
dtype: object
```

Comment: My data already is in the 'post-explosion' format. My values are times in the HH:mm format.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289579/plot-datetime-time-in-seaborn this works for scatterplot but not for violinplot.